# Hook for removing product from cart

Tags: 7, hooks, commerce

I am removing products from cart programmatically using such a code:

```
commerce_line_item_delete($line_item_id)
```

The problem is, I cannot find any hook, that would be invoked after removing product from cart.
I have tried [hook_commerce_cart_product_remove](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.api.php/function/hook_commerce_cart_product_remove/DC), but this hook is not called when removing product with [commerce_line_item_delete](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.module/function/commerce_line_item_delete/DC) function.

How can I remove product from cart programatically, so I can use hook after it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove product programatically, and still allow other modules to interact with this event, you should invoke hooks explicitly just after deletion using [`module_invoke_all`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7):

```
module_invoke_all('commerce_cart_product_remove', $order, $product, $quantity, $line_item);
```

That way you have a choice - you can call it and emulate regular deletion, or you can omit it, and prevent any marketing interactions etc that your user did not trigger.

Alternatively, because line items are entities, you should be able to hook into their deletion with generic [`hook_entity_delete`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_delete/7), without any modifications to the way you invoke deletion.